# Monte Carlo simulation to get stationary distribution of a complex system

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, stationarity

I was wondering if I could get some help with my problem.
I have a complex Markov chain where I cannot track its transition analytically. Instead, I decided to simulate $N$ numbers of particles for $T$ periods to get the particles' stationary distribution.

However, given that I have no theoretical benchmark to compare if this $N\times T$ simulation results really give me the stationary distribution, I had two questions in mind.

1. Ideally, $N$ should go to infinity to erase the error from discretization, and $T$ should also go to infinity to erase the error from initial conditions. Since this is impossible, what I do is as follows. I simulate for different $T$ for $N=1,000$ and check from which $T^{*}$ the distribution stays relatively stable. Then I take the average (equal-weighted sum of probability mass) of the distributions of $T^{*}+1$ to $T^{*}+5$. I thought this was as if I have $N =5,000$ samples.
2. The other way I thought of was to simulate five times of $N=1,000$ and $T=T^{*}$ and average them out.

I wondered if any of these two ways is a valid method.

Comment: Perfect sampling is a valid approach to simulate from the stationary distribution of a Markov chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for leaving the comment. Exactly which one is referred to as "perfect sampling"?

Comment: Neither of them qualifies as perfect sampling, I am suggesting you check this keyword in the MCMC literature see eg https://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/MHuber/Research/talks/Ulm_12_08_2003final.pdf

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much!